# UnsatisfiedDependencyException in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

We are getting No qualifying bean of type for below code in spring boot:

```
Main class:


package *.*.*;

@SpringBootApplication
public class BankApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BankApplication.class, args);
    }

}
package *.*.*.dataaccess.repository;


@Repository
public interface BankRepository extends JpaRepository<BankEntity, String> {

}

package *.*.*.dataaccess.dao;

@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "Bank")
public class BankEntity {

//fileds
}



package *.*.*.dataaccess.utils;


@Component
public class DBUtils {

    @Autowired
    BankRepository bnRepo;

    
     */
    public void saveBank(BankDto dto) {
        
        //preparing  bnEntity -entity
        
            this.bnRepo.saveAndFlush(bnEntity);     

    }
}
```

## Added below dependencies related to MySQL:
pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.wix/wix-embedded-mysql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.wix</groupId>
            <artifactId>wix-embedded-mysql</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

## getting error while testing this:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = { DBUtils.class })
public class BankTest {

    @Autowired
    DBUtils dbUtils;

    @Test
    public void saveAndFlishTest() {

        dbUtils.saveBank(getBankDetails()); // once this is working then will added junit checks using asserts
    }
}
```

## Error details as below:

> Caused by:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'DBUtils': Unsatisfied dependency
> expressed through field 'bnRepo'; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
> qualifying bean of type '*.*.*.dataaccess.repository.BankRepository'
> available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
> candidate. Dependency annotations:
> {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Answer (score 0):

`BankRepository` is not created hence the error - there is no bean of that type so there is nothing to inject (via autowiring).

You should check the following:

1. Spring Data is enabled
2. The `BankRepository` should reside in the package that is subject to package scanning in your spring boot application

Comment: all sub pkgs are in inside parent pkg only. @Mark Bramnik

Comment: Basically it depends on your package structure and the configuration. Do you have spring data in the class path? (org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa). Spring data when plugged in should generate the runtime proxy based on your repository defintions in the interface, obviously this doesn't happen, hence the error

Comment: how to check if Spring data is enabled? @Mark Bramnik

Comment: Logs probably or `-debug` option on start should provide you more information

Comment: Also make sure you have annotation `@EnableJpaRepositories`. See https://www.baeldung.com/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-data-jpa#config

Comment: usually springboot will auto enable repositories right why need to add that? @Mark Bramnik

Comment: What do you mean to "auto enable repositories"? Repositories are wrapped with runtime generate proxies - the code is generated based on your interface methods signatures. So Spring should know why repositories are "subject" for handling by spring data. Now I can't say for sure whether this is mandatory in newer spring boot/dat a versions (I'm not using spring data by myself), but its still worth checking IMO

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216912/discussion-between-krishna-and-mark-bramnik).